# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync throw "Internal Error" for Excel Online

Tags: office-js

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        url,
        {
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          displayInIframe: true, 
        },
)
```

The above code throws the following exception for **Excel Online**. It works fine for **Excel Mac**.

> message:"An internal error has occurred."
>
> name:"Internal Error"

Answer (score 0):

When you tried your code that API was not available in Excel Online yet. The API is now available so it should work fine now.  Let us know if that is not the case.